# How to simulate the C# attribute in Python

Tags: python, c#, unit-testing, attributes

Recently, I want to simulate the attribute of C# in python for my unit test cases.

```
class SmokeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @Tags(Tags.BVT)
    @TestCategory('login')
    def test_login(self):
        pass
```

If it is okay, I could write a test runner to search test cases with those attributes (like, I want to run all test cases with category **login**). After a long time of thinking, I got the following answer

```
class Attribute(object):
    '''
    To simulate `attribute` in C#
    '''
    def __call__(self, f):
        def wrapper(this, *args, **kwargs):
            return f(this, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            wrapper._attributes = f._attributes
            wrapper._attributes.append(self)
        except:
            wrapper._attributes = [self]
        return wrapper

class TestCategory(Attribute):
    '''
    Class used to specify the category of a unit test
    '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def Name(self):
        return self._name
```

The implementation is simple, just add a property '_attributes' for the functions to hold all ***attributes***. However, it looks somewhat ugly!

My question is is there any better solution?

Comment: FYI for adding to a function's attributes (in the OO sense) like this, you don't need a wrapper. Just create `f._attributes` if it's not there and append to it.

Comment: Hi delnan, you're right, the wrapper is redundant.